# How to change statistic text to String?

Tags: android, android-activity

guys.
I want to replace the statistical code for code that can receive text from strings.xml (in this case "App Name":

```
private final static String APP_TITLE = "App name";
```

This is [full code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yzuco33f3bijyd0/AppRater.java?dl=0).

Thank you!

P.S. Nope, getString doesn't work(

Comment: Well, you cannot change final Properties after you assigned something to them.

Comment: try getResources().getString(R.string.yourString);

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a property value, don't make it final static.
Instead you should do :

```
private  String appTitle = "App name";
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want a static String field to contain a value from resources?
You cannot initialize a static string from resources because resources are not available at that point. What you can do is

private static final int RES_ID = R.String.app_name;

and call getString(RES_ID) anywhere you would call APP_TITLE (or just once and save to a variable)

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is you don't have a context to get resources. This can be solved by getting a context **before** this field is initialized. A possible workaround for this is to create an `Application` class, set it's context to a static field, then used this field in your `Activty` to get the desired string.

Application class:

```
public class AppContext extends Application {

   public static Context cntx;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        cntx=getApplicationContext();
    }
}
```

Register it in the manifest:

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="Test"
        android:name=".AppContext"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="Test" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Activity:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final static String APP_TITLE = AppContext.cntx.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setText(APP_TITLE);
    }
}
```